# Is there any other method to obtain wavefunction and energy levels rather than perturbation theory or WKB approximation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, perturbation-theory, differential-equations

I want to solve the asymmetric double square well with infinite potentials problem for both wavefunction and energy levels but it is not solvable with solving Schrödinger's Equation. The resources I encountered claims that perturbation theory is an option for "small" perturbations and WKB approximation is usable if the potential is "slowly" varying. Are there any alternative mathematical or physical methods instead of both PT and WKB approximation?

Comment: To reopen this post (v2) consider to make title more focused.